# How to save a plot in R in a subdirectory of the working directory

Tags: r, plot, concatenation

Is it possible to save a plot in R into a subdirectory of the current working directory? I tried the following, but that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to concatenate the working directory to the file name I want.

```
  wd <- getwd()

  png(filename=wd+"/img/name.png")

  counts <- table(dnom$Variant, dnom$Time)
  barplot(counts, main="Distribution of Variant and words of time",
    xlab="Temporal nouns", col=c("paleturquoise3", "palegreen3"),
    legend = rownames(counts))
```

Also, what's the default save directory for the image export functions?

When running David's suggestion below the error returned is:

```
Error in png(filename = paste0(wd, "/img/name.png")) : 
  unable to start png() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(filename = paste0(wd, "/img/name.png")) :
  unable to open file 'D:/Dropbox/CorpuslinguÃ¯stiek project/antconc resultaten/img/name.png' for writing
2: In png(filename = paste0(wd, "/img/name.png")) : opening device failed
```

Comment: Probably just `png(filename = paste0(wd, "/img/name.png"))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg See my edit, I get an error when running your command.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works perfectly fine. The reason you are getting this error is because you don't have `img` file in your working directory. Also, don't forget `dev.off()` at the end.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I do not have this folder, indeed. Is it possible to create it in R? I will have to provide my script to colleagues and I don't want them to have too much manual labour. Also, isn't `dev.off()` only necessary when you want to close your device? What if I want to keep it open?

Comment: rather than `filename = paste0(wd, "/img/name.png")`, I would recommend `filename = file.path(wd, "img", "name.png")` which is more platform independant (i.e. works also under Windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
File <- "./img/name.png"
if (file.exists(File)) stop(File, " already exists")
dir.create(dirname(File), showWarnings = FALSE)

png(File)

# ... whatever ...

dev.off()
```

Omit the `if` statement if its ok to overwrite the file.

If `img` exists then `dir.create` could be optionally omitted. (If you try to create a directory that is already there it won't cause a problem.)

**Notes**

1) Another possility is to put `img` in the home directory. We could use `png("~/img/name.png")` to save the file to the `img` directory in the home directory.  If unsure which directory is the home directory try `path.expand("~")`.

2) Also note the `savePlot` command which is given after (rather than before) the plotting command.

Comment: If an image with that name already exists, will it overwrite it? Or throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
png(filename="new/name.png")    #will work if "new" folder is already in your working directory
data(mtcars)
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, main="Scatterplot Example",  xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)
dev.off()
```

If you do not already have the "new" folder in your working directory, you can create the same using `dir.create()` as mentioned in G. Grothendieck's answer.

Also, `dev.off()` is necessary as it shuts down the specified (by default the current) device. Without it, you cannot view the created image.

Comment: I know I can do it like that, but I want to be more efficient and do it with a var for the working directory instead.

Comment: @BramVanroy I have made changes above