# Saving each graph to the directory with its name on it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using for loop to save my graphs to the working directory what ever it is. OTH, I want to add one more feature that creating the directory with the graph name and store corresponding figures to those folder. For instance if the graph name is `setosa` create folder named `setosa` and store `setosa` graph to inside to that new directory.

There is a one relative [how-to-save-plots-inside-a-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592729/how-to-save-plots-inside-a-folder) here but no solution is clearly given.

Here is my current working code for saving graphs to working directory.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

plot_list = list() # Initialize an empty list
     for (i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  p = ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
     geom_point(size = 3, aes(colour = Species))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

for (i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  file_name = paste( i, ".tiff", sep="")
  tiff(file_name)
  print(plot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: See [Check existence of directory and create if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist) and [How to save a plot in R in a subdirectory of the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817546/how-to-save-a-plot-in-r-in-a-subdirectory-of-the-working-directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `file_name = ...` with:

```
...
file_name = paste0("./", i, "/", i, ".tiff")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

such as

```
 fillname<-paste0("./","mey", "/",i,".tiff",sep = "")
```

"mey" is the subdirectory folder.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you set `i` to `"setosa"`.

```r
i <- "setosa"
```

Using `file.path()` is IMHO the most idiomatic way to create the file name:

```r
filename <- file.path(".", i, paste0(i, ".tiff"))
```

This has the advantage of also being platform independent (as opposed to inserting `/` explicitly into path).

The only thing that remains is to ensure that the folder exists.

```r
dir.create(i, showWarnings = FALSE)
```

The `showWarnings = FALSE` option suppresses the warning if the folder already exists.