# How to save images returned with a loop in R to hard drive?

Tags: r, loops

I have a csv file with latitude and longitude coordinates. A sample:

```
Lat   Lon
94.2  13.4
32.2  12.4
89.3  24.4
```

The code below loops through these Lat/Lon coordinates, finds the associated image of this location on Google Street View, which I can then see in R Markdown below the code cell.

However, using the sample data above, 3 images are returned. I want to save them to my hard drive in a specific 'images' folder outside my working directory. Is there a way to do this?

```
# install.packages('googleway')

myfunction <- function(Lat, Lon){
  google_streetview(
  location = c(Lat, Lng), # lat/lon coordinates
  size = c(600, 400), # w x h
)
}

purrr::map2(data$Lat, data$Lon, myfunction)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot in R in a subdirectory of the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817546/how-to-save-a-plot-in-r-in-a-subdirectory-of-the-working-directory)

Comment: @R_Dax ish - it's just the loop in my code returns many images (10,000+) using the full data. I'd like them all to be downloaded to my external hard drive (since my computer's is too low to save that many images), but since there are so many images it would be impractical for me to name all using `filename`. Any ideas?

Comment: @RonakShah I haven't got one as I'm not sure what to use to save them. Ideally I'd like to save the images as jpegs without having to view them in R first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct a list containing you latitude/longitude pairs
2. Include the "save to disk" step inside your function that creates a single graph
3. Use `lapply` to apply the function to each element of your list in turn

For example, the following (untested) code should save your images in a series of files named `image00001.jpg`, `img00002`.jpg etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

positions <- list(c("lat"=94.2, "lon"=13.4),c("lat"=32.2, "lon"=12.4),c("lat"=89.3, "lon"=24.2))
imgCount <- 0
lapply(
  positions,
  function(x) {
    google_streetview(
      location = c(x$lat, x$lon), # lat/lon coordinates
      size = c(600, 400), # w x h
    )
    imgCount <<- imgCount + 1
    ggsave(paste0("image", sprintf("%05d", imgCount), ".jpg"))
  }
)
```

Note the use of `<<-` to ensure the counter increments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the following works? I cannot run `google_streetview()` because I don't have an API key. But If the output is a "plot", it should work.

In an intermediate step, we generated an `id` variable to be able to match each plot to each image and also a filename for each plot. You can adapt the filename to make sure it saves in the desired location.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(
  ~Lat,    ~Lon,
  94.2, 13.4, 
  32.2, 12.4, 
  89.3, 24.4
)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), 
         filename = paste0("./stview_", id, ".jpeg" ))

df

myfunction <- function(Lat, Lon, filename, ...){
  cat("Lat: ", Lat, "\n")
  cat("Lon", Lon, "\n")
  cat("filename", filename, "\n")
  
  png(filename) # opens device.

  google_streetview(
    location = c(Lat, Lon), # lat/lon coordinates
    size = c(600, 400), # w x h
    output = "plot"
  )

  dev.off() # closes device
  print(paste("Saved:", filename))
}


df %>%  pwalk(myfunction)
```